# What is $\sum_{j=1}^{L} \sin(\frac{\pi k_1 j}{L+1}) \sin(\frac{\pi k_2 j}{L+1}) e^{ijc}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm looking for a compact expression of $\sum_{j=1}^{L} \sin(\frac{\pi k_1 j}{L+1}) \sin(\frac{\pi k_2 j}{L+1}) e^{ijc}$ where $i$ is imaginary unit, $k_1$ and $k_2$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Have you tried to use the product to sum identity and then Euler's formula? Maybe it could work...

Answer (score 1):

Using Euler's formula $$\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)),$$ it is possible to write:
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi k_1 j}{L+1}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi k_2 j}{L+1}\right) =-\frac{1}{4}\left(exp\left(\frac{i\pi (k_1 +k_2) j}{L+1}\right)-\exp\left(\frac{i\pi (k_1 -k_2) j}{L+1}\right)-\exp\left(\frac{i\pi (k_2 -k_1) j}{L+1}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{-i\pi (k_1 +k_2) j}{L+1}\right)\right),
$$
so that
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi k_1 j}{L+1}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi k_2 j}{L+1}\right) e^{ijc}=-\frac{1}{4}\left(\exp\left(i\left(\frac{\pi (k_1 +k_2) }{L+1}+c\right)j\right)-\exp\left(i\left(\frac{\pi (k_1 -k_2) }{L+1}+c\right)j\right)-\exp\left(i\left(\frac{\pi (k_2 -k_1) }{L+1}+c\right)j\right)+\exp\left(-i\left(\frac{\pi (k_1 +k_2) }{L+1}+c\right)j\right)\right).
$$
Each of the four terms is of the form $\exp\left(iaj\right)$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^L \exp\left(iaj\right)=\frac{\exp(ia)\left(\exp(iaL)-1\right)}{\exp(ia)-1}.$$ Plugging this in the expression given above, you will obtain a closed form expression for your sum, although I would hardly call it a "compact" expression.

I hope I did not make any typos in my elaboration, be sure to cross-check.